# Is it true that $T(\vec{v}-\vec{w})=\vec{0}$ implies that $\vec{v}=\vec{w}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to come to grips with a certain portion of the proof of the Kernel-Rank theorem. In this particular portion, we have the following claim. We posit that $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ are vector spaces, and that $T:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}$ is linear. In addition, we posit that $\psi=\lbrace\vec{\varphi}_1,\vec{\varphi}_2,\cdots,\vec{\varphi}_m\rbrace$ is a basis for $\mathrm{Im}(T)$. We also suppose that $\vec{e}_{k+i}\in\mathbb{V}$ is such that $T(\vec{e}_{k+i})=\vec{\varphi}_i$ for $1\leq i\leq m$. Now we let $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in\mathbb{V}$ be such that $T(\vec{v})=\lambda_{k+1}\vec{\varphi}_1+\lambda_{k+2}\vec{\varphi}_2+\ldots+\lambda_{k+m}\vec{\varphi}_m$ and $\vec{w}=\lambda_{k+1}\vec{e}_{k+1}+\lambda_{k+2}\vec{e}_{k+2}+\ldots+\lambda_{k+m}\vec{e}_{k+m}$. Therefore we have
$$
T(\vec{w})=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_{k+i}\vec{e}_{k+i}\right)
$$
$$
T(\vec{w})=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_{k+i}T(\vec{e}_{k+i})
$$
$$
T(\vec{w})=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_{k+i}\vec{\varphi}_i
$$
$$
T(\vec{w})=T(\vec{v})
$$
The question I have is why $T(\vec{w})=T(\vec{v})$ does not imply that $\vec{w}=\vec{v}$, since, in my mind, the only way that $T(\vec{v})=\lambda_{k+1}\vec{\varphi}_1+\lambda_{k+2}\vec{\varphi}_2+\ldots+\lambda_{k+m}\vec{\varphi}_m$, is if $\vec{v}=\lambda_{k+1}\vec{e}_{k+1}+\lambda_{k+1}\vec{e}_{k+2}+\ldots+\lambda_{k+m}\vec{e}_{k+m}$, meaning $\vec{v}=\vec{w}$, but I get the impression that is not the case from the remainder of the proof. Any response is appreciated.

For completeness, I'll include the rest of the proof. The proof aims to show that if $\varepsilon=\lbrace\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2,\cdots,\vec{e}_k\rbrace$ is a basis for $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$, then $\epsilon=\lbrace\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2,\cdots,\vec{e}_k,\vec{e}_{k+1},\vec{e}_{k+2},\cdots,\vec{e}_{k+m}\rbrace$ is a basis for $\mathbb{V}$. The portion of the proof in question is tasked with showing that $\epsilon$ spans. It therefore uses the fact that $T(\vec{v})=T(\vec{w})$ to conclude that $\vec{v}-\vec{w}\in\mathrm{Ker}(T)$, and therefore we may write
$$
\vec{v}-\vec{w}=\lambda_1\vec{e}_1+\lambda_2\vec{e}_2+\ldots+\lambda_m\vec{e}_m
$$
$$
\vec{v}=\lambda_1\vec{e}_1+\lambda_2\vec{e}_2+\ldots+\lambda_m\vec{e}_m+\vec{w}
$$
$$
\vec{v}=\lambda_1\vec{e}_1+\lambda_2\vec{e}_2+\ldots+\lambda_m\vec{e}_m+\lambda_1\vec{e}_{k+1}+\lambda_2\vec{e}_{k+2}+\ldots+\lambda_m\vec{e}_{k+m}
$$
$$
\therefore\vec{v}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+m}\lambda_i\vec{e}_i
$$
As required. The reason why it bothers me that $\vec{v}$ could equal $\vec{w}$ is because then the first line of this working would essentially be
$$
\vec{0}=\lambda_1\vec{e}_1+\lambda_2\vec{e}_2+\ldots+\lambda_m\vec{e}_m
$$
Which, I feel, is not helpful for the proof. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just read the title. My first thought would be to say "no" because we can take $T=0$ and $v\neq w$.

Comment: $T(v-w)=0$ implies $v=w$ when $T$ is injective, because in this case we have $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: In general, $T(v) = T(w)$ if and only if $v = w + n$ where $n$ is an element of the kernel of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

$T(v-w)=0$ if and only if $v-w \in \ker T$.

This means you can conclude that $v-w=0$ (i.e.,  $v=w$) if and only if $\ker T$ contains only the single element $0$.

And this happens if and only if $T$ is injective (1-1).

Comment: In the event that $T$ is not injective, it's still possible that $v=w$, since $T(0)=0$, so is there any feature of this proof that stops this from being the case? Or better yet, is it possible that $v=w$, but the proof is still valid?

Comment: It is certainly *possible* that $v=w$, you just can’t *conclude* that from the statement that $T(v-w)=0$ unless $T$ is injective.