# Is it true that $T$ is injective $\iff$ $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\lbrace\vec{0}\rbrace$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

This is related to a previous question that I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488390/is-it-true-that-t-vecv-vecw-vec0-implies-that-vecv-vecw/3488415?noredirect=1#comment7174177_3488415). The question this time asks whether or not, if $T:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}$ is linear, then $T$ is injective $\iff$ $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\lbrace\vec{0}\rbrace$. I've devised a proof of my own regarding why this is true. Proving $\implies$ is trivial, since we know that for $T$ to be linear, $T(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$, and thus $T(\vec{v})=\vec{0}\implies\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, and thus $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\lbrace\vec{0}\rbrace$. Proving $\impliedby$ is a little more tricky. Suppose that $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in\mathbb{V}$ are such that $\vec{v}\neq\vec{w}$ and $T(\vec{v})=T(\vec{w})$. Then, since $\vec{v}\neq\vec{w}$, we have that $\vec{v}-\vec{w}\neq\vec{0}$, but since $T(\vec{v})=T(\vec{w})$, we have that $T(\vec{v}-\vec{w})=\vec{0}$, which implies that $\vec{v}-\vec{w}\in\mathrm{Ker}(T)$. But since $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\lbrace\vec{0}\rbrace$, and $\vec{v}-\vec{w}\neq\vec{0}$, we know that this cannot be possible, and thus $T$ must be injective.

I'm looking to establish whether or not this is true, as it's effectively the only fact that I need to confirm to complete the proof of the Kernel-Rank theorem. Any responses are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This argument is correct. You can simplify the second step while retaining the same idea without turning it into a proof by contradiction: If $T(v)=T(w)$, then, by linearity, $T(v-w)=0$, meaning $v-w\in\mathrm{ker}(T)=\{0\}$, i.e. $v-w=0$ and $v=w$; thus $T$ is injective.

Comment: Your proof is great. From a stylistc perspective, I'd just advise you to either go the *reductio ad absurdum* route (which is what you did without making it explicit), or to not assume that $v\neq w$ and conclude that from $T(v) = T(w)$ it follows that $v=w$ (and hence that $T$ is injective).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you proved it so it is true. You could try the following straightforward, short method

$$T\;\text{ is injective}\;\iff \left(Tv=Tu\implies v=u\right)\iff \left(Tv-Tu=0\implies v=u\right)\iff $$

$$\iff \left(T(v-u)=0\implies v-u=0\right)\iff\left(Tx=0\implies x=0\right)\iff \ker T=\{0\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is almost OK.

If $T$ is linear then $\{\vec{0}\}\subset Ker (T)$  and not $Ker (T)=\{\vec{0}\}$.

It is equal because $T$ is injective. Take any $\vec{v} \in Ker (T)$. Then $T(\vec{0})= \vec{0}= T(\vec{v})$ we get $\vec{0}=\vec{v}$ and thus $Ker (T)=\{\vec{0}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$T(u)=T(v)\implies u-v\in kerT$ since the kernel consists of only the zero vector, $u=v$. That's all you need to say for this particular direction.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand,  you can use the rank nullity theorem to prove *it*.  For the kernel is trivial iff the nullity is zero iff $T$ has full rank.